# How to omit custom logging handler on special condition?

Tags: python, logging, mysql-python

I wrote custom handler that puts log messages into MySQL database. I want to use this handler only if I was connected properly using **mysql-connector** python library. Otherwise I want to omit this handler.

```py
class LogDBHandler(logging.Handler):
    """Customized logging handler that puts logs to the database."""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table_name = 'log'
        self.counter = 0
        self.chunk = []
        self.sql_conn, self.sql_cursor = self.connect_to_db()
        # create log table if doesn't exist
        try:
            self.create_table()
        except mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError:
            pass

    @staticmethod
    def connect_to_db():
        """Connect to MySQL database to perform logging."""
        credentials = {
            "user": os.environ.get("DARWIN_DB_USER"),
            "password": os.environ.get("DARWIN_DB_PASSWORD"),
            "host": os.environ.get("DARWIN_DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1"),
            "port": os.environ.get("DARWIN_DB_PORT", "3306"),
            "database": os.environ.get("DARWIN_DB_NAME"),
        }
        db = mysql.connector.connect(**credentials)
        cursor = db.cursor()
        return db, cursor
    ...
```

This is logging configuration file, where I store all loggers, handlers etc.

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=root, db

[formatters]
keys=formatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=root, db

[handler_root]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=formatter
args=('darwin.log', 'w')

[handler_db]
class=libs.logger.LogDBHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=formatter
args=()

[formatter_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)-12s - %(levelname)-8s - %(message)s
```

Everything works fine if database credentials are valid. If they are wrong `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError` exception is raised. Instead of shutting down entire program I would like to omit this custom handler if `self.connect_to_db()` raises exception . Any ideas how to achieve such thing?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1):

Reedit with a working mock:

```
class LogDBHandler(logging.Handler):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.sql_conn = None
        try:
            self.sql_conn, self.sql_cursor = self.connect_to_db()
        except:
            return None
    def emit(self, msg):
        pass

logging.handlers.LogDBHandler = LogDBHandler
```

Main:
    import logging.config
    from logdbhandler import LogDBHandler
    logging.config.fileConfig( 'logconf.yaml', )

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
for l in logger.handlers:
    if isinstance(l, LogDBHandler):
        if not l.sql_conn:
            logger.removeHandler(l)

print(logger.handlers)
```

Comment: I will catch the exception, that's for sure. I want to know is there a way to somehow tell root logger object to omit this specific handler while being inside __init__() method.  Appeling to your answer code - if connection is established properly - create_table and so on .. but on **else** I need to somehow write logic to omit this handler.

Comment: I do not know of a way to remove the handler during the __init__() method. Raising an exception will end your fileConfig().
The easiest way to determine if the LogDBHandler needs to be discarded seems to be as edited into my answer.

Comment: I tried your edited solution, but when I call `logger.handlers` empty list is returned.

Comment: I did another edit and this code does work for me as a mock.
But you might want to think about moving the connection to the database into a @property called from the emit class with cleanup in close. Because you will run into trouble if the database restarts or the firewall drops the connection  during run time of your script.

Comment: I posted code that finally works. Anyway thanks for your help. I'm very gratefull

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me. I'm aware it's not elegant, but it works.

```py
class LogDBHandler(logging.Handler):
    """Customized logging handler that puts logs to the database."""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table_name = 'log'
        self.counter = 0
        self.chunk = []
        self.sql_conn = self.connect_to_db()
        if self.sql_conn:
            self.sql_cursor = self.sql_conn.cursor()
            # create log table if doesn't exist
            self.create_log_table()
        else:
            print("DB Connection error")

    def emit(self, record):
        """Called on each log attempt."""
        if self.sql_conn:
            timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                                      time.localtime(record.created))
            self.chunk.append((record.name, record.levelname,
                               str(record.getMessage()), timestamp))
            self.counter += 1
            # Insert chunk of data into DB
            if self.counter % 1000 == 0:
                self.insert_chunk()

    def flush(self):
        """
        Handler destructor, close all db connection and insert final
        records into db.
        """
        if self.sql_conn:
            # Insert last chunk of data
            self.insert_chunk()
            # Close connection with DB
            self.sql_cursor.close()
            self.sql_conn.close()

    @staticmethod
    def connect_to_db():
        """Connect to MySQL database to perform logging."""
        credentials = {
            "user": os.environ.get("DARWIN_DB_USER"),
            "password": os.environ.get("DARWIN_DB_PASSWORD"),
            "host": os.environ.get("DARWIN_DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1"),
            "port": os.environ.get("DARWIN_DB_PORT", "3306"),
            "database": os.environ.get("DARWIN_DB_NAME"),
        }
        try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(**credentials)
            return connection
        except mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError:
            return None
```

Answer (score 0):

May be someone will benefit from the one I have eventually created for myself:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Copied and modified from https://github.com/onemoretime/mySQLHandler/
"""
import MySQLdb
import logging
import time
 
class mySQLHandler(logging.Handler):
    """
    Logging handler for MySQL db.
    """

    check_sql = """SHOW TABLES LIKE '{log_table}';"""

    create_sql = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {log_table}(
    Created text,
    Name text,
    LogLevel int,
    LogLevelName text,
    Message text,
    Args text,
    Module text,
    FuncName text,
    LineNo int,
    Exception text,
    Process int,
    Thread text,
    ThreadName text
    )"""

    insert_sql = """INSERT INTO {log_table}(
    Created,
    Name,
    LogLevel,
    LogLevelName,
    Message,
    Args,
    Module,
    FuncName,
    LineNo,
    Exception,
    Process,
    Thread,
    ThreadName
    )
    VALUES (
    "{dbtime}",
    "{name}",
    {levelno},
    "{levelname}",
    "{msg}",
    "{args}",
    "{module}",
    "{funcName}",
    {lineno},
    "{exc_text}",
    {process},
    "{thread}",
    "{threadName}"
    );
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Customized logging handler that puts logs to MySQL db.
        """
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.host = kwargs['host']
        self.port = kwargs['port']
        self.dbuser = kwargs['dbuser']
        self.dbpassword = kwargs['dbpassword']
        self.dbname = kwargs['dbname']
        self.log_table = kwargs['log_table']
        self.sql_conn, self.sql_cursor =  self.connect_to_db()

    def connect_to_db(self):
        """
        Connect to MySQL database to perform logging.
        Create log table if does not exist.
        """
        try:
            conn=MySQLdb.connect(host=self.host,port=self.port,user=self.dbuser,passwd=self.dbpassword,db=self.dbname)
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(mySQLHandler.check_sql.format(log_table = self.log_table))
            conn.commit()
            table_exist = cur.fetchone()
            if not table_exist:
                cur.execute(mySQLHandler.create_sql.format(log_table = self.log_table))
                conn.commit()
            return conn, cur
        except Exception: # ignoring connection and table creation exceptions as this handler meant to be used with application db
            return None, None

    def flush(self):
        """
        Override to implement custom flushing behaviour for MySQLdb connection.
        """
        if self.sql_conn:
            self.sql_cursor.close()
            self.sql_conn.close()

    def formatDBTime(self, record):
        """
        Time formatter.
        """
        record.dbtime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(record.created))

    def emit(self, record):
        """
        Emit a record to MySQL db.
        Format the record and send it to the specified database.
        """
        if self.sql_conn:
            try:
                self.format(record)
                self.formatDBTime(record)
                record.exc_text = logging._defaultFormatter.formatException(record.exc_info).replace('"', "'").replace('\n','').replace('\r','') if record.exc_info else ""
                if isinstance(record.msg, str): record.msg = record.msg.replace("'", "''")
                sql_stmt = mySQLHandler.insert_sql.format(**record.__dict__, log_table = self.log_table)
                self.sql_cursor.execute(sql_stmt)
                self.sql_conn.commit()
            except Exception:
                self.sql_conn.rollback()
                self.handleError(record)
```

logging.conf looks like this:

```html
[handler_mySQLHandler]
#class=logging.handlers.mySQLHandler
class=mySQLHandler.mySQLHandler
kwargs={"host":"hostname", "port":3306, "dbuser":"dubber", "dbpassword": "password", "dbname": "dbname", "log_table":"syslog"}
```